# Consulta con acento Doctrine + Symfony + PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

Tengo un método en el repositorio de Doctrine para buscar a una persona como este:

```
function search($value)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->like(
        'LOWER(p.lastName)',
        "'%" . mb_strtolower($value) . "%'"));
}
```

Ejemplo:

| No | Name | Last name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luis | Sanchez |
| 2 | David | Sánchez |

Cuando uso este método y la entrada es 'Sánchez' solo devuelve el registro No. 1, y si la entrada es 'Sánchez' solo devuelve el registro No. 2 (Cambie a por á). Necesito obtener todos los registros de mi base de datos sin importar si la entrada contiene algún acento (á, é, í, ó, ú).

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql dispone del operador SIMILAR TO. DQL no incluye soporte para este operador por defecto. Tendrás que registrarlo. Por ejemplo:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\InputParameter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Node;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

/**
 * UnsenFunction ::= "SimilarTo" "(" StringPrimary ","Regex")"
 */
class SimilarTo extends FunctionNode
{
    /** @var Node */
    protected $field;
    /** @var Node */
    protected $query;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->field = $parser->StringExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->query = $parser->StringExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return '(' . $this->field->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ' SIMILAR TO ' . $this->query->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }
}
```

Y luego registrarla en tu configuración de doctrine:

```yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                similar_to: App\DQL\SimilarTo
```

Ahora podrás escribir en tus consultas:

```php
$qb->where("similar_to(e.nombre, :search_term) = true");
```

Donde `:search_term` será una cadena del modo `'S|s|á|a|Á|A|N|n|C|c|H|h|é|e|E|É|Z|z'`

Puedes escribir tu propia función para generar las distintas variaciones de un caracter y agregar el caracter '%' dependiendo del modo de búsqueda.